# Prove that if $\lvert a_{n}-L\rvert < \varepsilon,$ then $ |a_{n}| < | L |+ \varepsilon.$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I was thinking of using the circle inequality or the reverse triangle inequality:

$\varepsilon > |a_{n}- L| \geqslant ||a_{n}|-|L|| .$

But then I have to assume that $|a_{n}| \geqslant |L|$ to get $|a_{n}| - |L| < \varepsilon$ and so $|a_{n}| < |L| + \varepsilon.$

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just the triangle inequality: 
$$ |a_n| = |L + (a_n - L)| \le |L| + |a_n - L| < |L|+\epsilon $$

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to assume anything, because $x\le|x|$ is true for all $x$. Try it: $4\le |4|$, $-10\le |-10|=10$...

Put another way, in the case that $|a_n|<|L|$, we have
$$ |a_n|-|L| < 0 < |L| - |a_n|$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof from scratch. Note that

$\tag1 |a_n-L|<\epsilon\Leftrightarrow -\epsilon<a_n-L<\epsilon \Leftrightarrow L-\epsilon<a_n<L+\epsilon$ and

$\tag2L\le |L|\ \text{and}\ L\ge -|L|$

Putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together, it follows that

$\tag3 -(|L|+\epsilon)<a_n<|L|+\epsilon$

which means that

$\tag4 |a_n|<||L|+\epsilon|=|L|+\epsilon$